# Nginx RTMP reconnect after peer reset a connection

Tags: linux, nginx, rtmp, live-video

I stream video to different streaming services (facebook live, google, ok.ru, and vk.com) using nginx-rtmp module. All streaming services works fine, exept vk.com, which randomly reset connection.
log file:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer), client:
95.213.11.125:443
```

For redirect stream to its target i using `on_publish` directive.
How can I reconnect stream to its destination after that

```
[info] 18793#0: *104 disconnect
[info] 18506#0: *202 deleteStream
```

Thx!
My nginx.conf:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 8192;
        max_message 10M;
        ping 120s;
        ping_timeout 5s;
        idle_streams off;
        buflen 10s;

application output0 {
                live on;
                meta on;
                sync 10ms;
                wait_video on;
                allow publish all;
                on_publish http://127.0.0.1/site/stream?id=1;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should show the relevant code.

Comment: My nginx.conf code: `rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 8192;
        max_message 10M;
        ping 120s;
        ping_timeout 5s;
        idle_streams off;
        buflen 10s;
 
application output0 {
                live on;
                meta on;
                sync 10ms;
                wait_video on;
                allow publish all;
                on_publish http://127.0.0.1/site/stream?id=1;
  }
}`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)